# Django: Celery can't find my app

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-celery

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapp'
```

I'm not really understanding what the problem is here. There are no issues with my app, but celery can't seem to find it no matter what I try and change.

Here is my directory structure:

```
django
 / mysite
     __init__.py
     celery.py
     settings.py
     urls.py
     wsgi.py
     / myapp
       admin.py
       apps.py
       models.py
       tasks.py
       urls.py
       views.py
   manage.py
```

celery.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')

app = Celery('myapp')

# Using a string here means the worker don't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

Command: `celery -A myapp worker -l info`

Comment: First command result: `AttributeError: module 'celery' has no attribute 'celery'`

Second command result: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapp'`

Comment: I've added an edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your **init**.py file contains the following:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app. from .celery_worker import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

Also, make sure that your celery.py looks something along the lines of this

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
import mysite

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')

app = Celery('wellfie')

# Using a string here means the worker don't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

Make sure that your tasks are properly recognized as well:
for instance a shared task would look like

`@shared_task(name="mysite.myapp.tasks.simple_task")`
Edit.

Actually you need to move the myapp out of mysite and into the Django folder. I would rename the Django folder to mysite as well, so that you have the parent folder mysite, child folder mysite, that holds wsgi, celery, settings etc, child folder myapp

Comment: My code looks just like this and I'm still getting the same errors.

Comment: @dcolumbus actually you need to move the myapp out of mysite and into the Django folder. I would rename the Django folder to mysite as well, so that you have the parent folder mysite, child folder mysite, that holds wsgi, celery, settings etc, child folder myall

Comment: `[2017-05-08 21:53:56,629: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 61] Connection refused.
Trying again in 4.00 seconds...`

Comment: Now a silly question - but do you have the ampq installed and running? @dcolumbus

Answer (score -1):

Your `celery.py` file should be in `myapp` folder. (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html)

You should run celery -A myapp worker -l info in `mysite` folder.

Comment: `[2017-05-08 21:53:56,629: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 61] Connection refused.
Trying again in 4.00 seconds...`

Comment: You haven't run your rabbitmq broker.

Comment: What is the solution for this?

Comment: The link you've mentioned talks about keeping celery.py in proj/proj/celery.py